# How to remove port number from url?

Tags: port-forwarding, tomcat, http-proxy, haproxy

My application "XY" running on port 1234 in tomcat server. I'm using HA-Proxy for loadbalancing. So in loadbalancing my front end port is 5678 to access the "XY" application through browser. Right now, I'm accessing htp://abc.game.com:5678/index.html. I want to access the same url but without port number. Because every time I've to remember port number to access application. How I can achieve this? 
There are multiple applications running in similar way, and same way it is configured haproxy.conf(centos 6)

Answer (score 2):

Ports 80 and 443 are the standard ports for http and https, respectively. If you use these ports for your application (instead of port 5678) then you won't need to specify the port number in your URLs.

Comment: There are multiple applications configured in haproxy. Its not possible to run every app in 80 or 443. One more thing is all app dont have public ip's

Comment: If haproxy isn't up to the job then replace it with something that is, such as a BigIP from F5. Re the port numbers, unless you move to port 80 (http) or port 443 (https) you _cannot_ remove the port numbers from your URLs. Re public IP, I don't see the problem: just don't listen on the public IP addresses for those server domains.

Comment: @roaima : I am trying to replace the port number in the url because the redirect works fine only without the url. I have created a backend which points to the IP along with the port number which makes my custom URL not to use the port number. Could you please explain why I cannot remove port number from the URL? here is the better description of my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418024/haproxy-remove-port-number-from-url